# deserialize json file data in mvc

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I have one json file in my local path sendmail.json it contains data like this

```
{
"from": {
    "datatype": "String",
    "required": false
},
"subject": {
    "datatype": "String",
    "required": false
},
"text": {
    "datatype": "String",
    "required": false
},
"to": {
    "datatype": "String",
    "required": false
}
```

}

i want to deserialize this data in mvc and i want to pass this data to .js angular controller please provide the way how to do it.

Comment: You might want to share what you've already tried so far. Also check your grammar and punctuations while posting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deserialize JSON and sent it to the client side, you can do it like this.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult mailData()
{
    List<test> myDeserializedObjList = (List<test>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Request["jsonString"], typeof(List<test>));
    return Json(jsonString, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Hope it works for you..!

Comment: what is test how to write a test class

Comment: test is a model which you can make from your json data, and use it in the List<test>, if you want to make model of your json data try this.     http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to deserialize the JSON into an object and then serialize the object into JSON to send it to the browser.

Why not send directly the JSON file to the browser?

```
public class MailController : Controller
{
    // GET: Mail
    public ActionResult Schema()
    {
        return File(this.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/sendmail.json"), "application/json");
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Anyway here you have what you asked for:

```
public class MailController : Controller
{
    // GET: Mail
    public ActionResult Schema()
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(this.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/sendmail.json")))
        {
            var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, PropertyDefinition>>(json);
            return this.Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}

public class PropertyDefinition
{
    public string datatype;
    public bool required;
}
```

It needs [Newtonsoft.JSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) nuget package